# How can I configure a timeout attribute to kitchen instance

Tags: test-kitchen

My kitchen instance is configured with 256 memory ram, but it is running very slow. Then my questions are:

How can I configure it to improve the memory ram size?

Is there any tutorial or post where I can find a solution?

Comment: Can the title be changed to match the content of the question? The title is about setting a timeout, but the content is about changing the VMs RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It varies based on the Test Kitchen driver. Heres an example for vagrant:

```
 driver:
   name: vagrant
   customize:
   memory: 1024
```